# Customising registration form to remove fields

Tags: curity

I've customised the curity v8.4.1 registration form by providing an overriding template in `/overrides/authenticator/html-form/create-account/get.vm` when I visit the registration page I correctly get the amended page.

However, the page validation still fires for all the fields I had removed from the template.

Specifically I don't want to collect/require telephone, and I want the email to be the username.

Can someone give some pointers to what I need to do to remove the validation and make it reflect the fields in the template.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using the Curity database schema, the phone number is mandatory. If you are sure you won’t use features that requires phone you may change the restriction on the table to allow for an empty value. Scripts to create the tables are in `/opt/idsvr/etc` for different databases.

Comment: Thanks! In this instance I removed the Unique constraint on the PhoneNumber field and the form validation started working as required.